# How do i modify the command to read temperature and time

Tags: macos, command-line

How do I modify the command `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "CPU die temperature"` to also provide a timestamp in terminal?

Comment: This will display the line that contains the time stamp for the first command `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -E "Sampled system activity|CPU die temperature"`

Comment: What’s the eventual use case? Dumping to a text file - getting the date/time in the prompt? There are really a lot of ways to skin this cat - so if you wanted to show exactly what you seek - we might have some cool ways to get you precisely what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I use `date -u` before commands.

```
date -u && sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "CPU die temperature"
```

Answer (score 0):

`powermetrics` logs indefinitely by default. From `man powermetrics`:

```
     -n N, --sample-count N
             Obtain N periodic samples (0=infinite) [default: 0]
```

If you want to timestamp measurements repeatedly (ex. in a loop / `cron`) use `-n 1` in combination with `date -u` so that it exits immediately:

```
date -u && sudo powermetrics -n 1 --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature"
```